# console showing script loading failed in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

problem(showing in console)

```
GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/vendors/css/vendors.min.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 580ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 1153ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 885ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 2443ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/themes/semi-dark-layout.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 2158ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/themes/dark-layout.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 1917ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/components.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 1664ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/colors.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 1405ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 2671ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/pages/authentication.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 3185ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets-sep/assets/css/style.css
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 3580ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/images/pages/login.png
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 5053ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 3878ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/core/app-menu.js
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 4127ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/core/app.js
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 4425ms]

GEThttp://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/components.js
[HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 4681ms]

Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js”. 127.0.0.1:8000:297:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/core/app-menu.js”. 127.0.0.1:8000:302:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/core/app.js”. 127.0.0.1:8000:303:1
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/components.js”. 127.0.0.1:8000:304:1
```

This is my problem. when I load my website, its frontend UI is gone, only shown the basic HTML structure. I tried every thing to make it to correct but I cant make it.

code from my layout

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap-extended.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/colors.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/components.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/themes/dark-layout.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/themes/semi-dark-layout.css') }}">

        <!-- BEGIN: Page CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('vuexy-assets/css/core/menu/menu-types/vertical-menu.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('vuexy-assets/css/core/colors/palette-gradient.css') }}">
        <!-- END: Page CSS-->




 <script  src="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/vendors.min.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Page Vendor JS-->
    <script src="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/vendors/js/ui/jquery.sticky.js') }}"></script>
    <!-- END: Page Vendor JS-->

    <!-- BEGIN: Theme JS-->
    <script src="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/js/core/app-menu.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/js/core/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/js/scripts/components.js') }}"></script>
```

my page currently looks like this
[image: current view of page]

what I tried

```
install npm 
npm run div
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan install  bootstrap ui
```

I also tried installing yarn, and also did sass-loader degrade to "sass-loader": "10.1.1", from 11.0.0

Comment: Hi, Please check whether you are getting proper path in here `{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap.css') }}`

Comment: Also, you can see the dev tools and check whether the elements have css applied or not.

Comment: this is the  path  on console GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/vuexy-assets/css/bootstrap.css

Comment: I solve it. by removing \public from my link.

Comment: Great :-). Write it as answer and accept it, so if anyone faces something similar, they will find the answer easily.

Comment: @chacko if you [read the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory), you have never to use `public` in your routes. It is always available for assets...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Laravel's asset helper points to public folder inside your application folder. If your assets are placed there, then your asset path should be like this.

```
<a href="{{ asset('vuexy-assets/css/components.css') }}"></a>
```

Instead of

```
<a href="{{ asset('/vuexy-assets/css/components.css') }}"></a>
```

If your assets are outside from public directory, then please make a magic link between that directory and public directory.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite link  from

```
<a href="{{asset(public/vuexy-assets/css/components.css')}}"></a>
```

To

```
<a href="{{asset(vuexy-assets/css/components.css')}}"></a>
```

This will correct the following errors.